# New to a webhost and nothing linked is appearing

Tags: links, web-hosting

I have a problem with my new web host. I recently switched my site from a free to a paid host and it was working fine on the free. Now however, when I go to the index page no formatting or anything remote (style sheets, images, etc.) is appearing. And whenever I click on a link on the index page it gives me [this](http://www.last.fm/music/Mon-tag/_/Pain+Of+Love?autostart) page, that isn't even on my site! Does anyone know the solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Check your paths where you link your assets from. First try absolute paths where you'll have:`http://site.com/css/style.css` then once you verify that works, find your relative paths which will look like this `../css/style.css`

Comment: Thanks, it ended up being something weird regarding hotlink protection.